# Multiple subscriptions with the same apple ID

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

We’re working on an app that allows users to register an account and create a “Business” that can list its menu, offers, branches, and many other details. We have a registration phase where the user signs in using email OTP. We want to follow a business model that includes renewable subscriptions where each subscription is associated with a business such that if the user subscribes using business A, signs out, and registers a new business B, the new business B would be on the basic plan and the user must be able to subscribe again using the business B, but since payments are associated with the Apple ID, apple will see the newer business B as already subscribed and will throw an error saying that you’re already subscribed. We thought about having different subscription groups where each group would correspond to a different business, so in the above example business A would have a subscription from Group 1, and business B would have a subscription from Group 2. We would then store each business subscription metadata in our server so that we can differentiate which business is subscribed from which subscription group and so on.

Is there any better alternative than what we came up with or any hassles/limitations in the above approach that we’re not seeing now?